# How can I save a variable in my function to use it again?

Tags: c++

I am working on something as a starter at coding, I want to get better so I'm practicicing by making a small program. Now, my aim is to attack a monster and then display its hp and then attack again and display the new HP. I've tried many different loops but each time the program doesn't save the new hp and just gives me the same hp instead of taking it away further. Any help is greatly appreciated, I've tried looking online but I can't seem to find an answer for this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
int hollowHP();
int blade();

int main() {
   srand(time(NULL));
   int damage = blade();
   int health = hollowHP();
   int newHP = health - damage;
   int newDamage = rand() % 11;
   int remainingHP = newHP - newDamage;
   string answer;
   cout << "A hollow stands before you with " << hollowHP() << " amount of HP!" 
      << endl;

   cout << "fight or flight?" << endl;
   cin >> answer;
   if (answer == "fight") { cout << "Your blade did " << damage << " amount of 
      damage!" << endl << "the hollow now has: " << newHP << " HP" << endl; }
   if (answer == "flight") { cout << "You have failed to protect those in need, 
      others will come to take the job off your hands.. coward." << endl; }
   do {
      cout << "continue fighting?" << endl;
      cin >> answer;
      if (answer == "yes") {
         cout << "Your next attack did " << newDamage << " amount of damage!" 
            << endl << "the hollow now has: " << newHP - newDamage << " HP" << endl;
      } if (answer == "no") {
         cout << "you tried i guess" << endl;
      }
   } while (health != 0);

   cout << "Hurray! You've defeated the hollow and saved many innocent lives! 
      You're a true hero." << endl;
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}

int hollowHP() {
   int hollow = 50;
   return hollow;
}

int blade() {
   int slash = 1;
   int spiritEnergy = rand() % 11;
   int totalSlash;

   totalSlash = slash + spiritEnergy;
   return totalSlash;
}
```

Comment: You’re not updating the health value in the loop. You should add something like health-=blade()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Onk_r has the right answer: static variables within the body ({}) of a function 'stick around'. Specifically, the expression which initializes the value of a static variable within a function body is executed only once, so the next time you call that function whatever value it had last will remain.

However, that won't solve your problem: your code is written with the assumption that every time you use a variable the expression that initialized it will be executed. When you use the name `damage`, for instance, the program will not execute the function `blade()`. Damage will only receive the value returned by `blade()` the one time, when you declared the variable `damage`:

`int damage = blade();`

That line only ever executes once in the whole lifetime of the program. Similarly, `newHP` will only ever have the value of `health - damage` at the time it was initialized. When `damage` was initialized, if `blade()` returned 8, then newHP will always have the value 42;

C++ doesn't store expressions; it evaluates them. That is what the type system ensures: the type stored in `damage` is `int`, it cannot have the type "expression" (not a thing in C++, though there are all kinds of ways implementing something like that). When you assign a variable, the value of the expression is stored, not how it was calculated. Every time the user attacks you really need to do something like:

`newHP = health - blade();
/* Output message */
health = newHP;`

Like Norhther said.

You are relying on functions to store state here, too, which isn't *bad* but in C++ you can, and generally should, do better. Specifically, `class Hollow` or the easier `struct Hollow` would be better than some variables floating around inside `main()`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain that thoroughly. Greatly appreciated. I've learnt a lot from this.

Comment: No problem, @KasayaHikaru. I recommend you read (or consult when you need to) the [ISO C++ Mega FAQ](https://isocpp.org/faq) if you are serious about learning C++. Until you get to C++14 stuff, it's an engaging read and will tell you alot.

Answer (score 0):

for saving value in `function` in `C++` or `C` for future use you can simply declare it as `static` and when leaves I mean `return` from function *set that variable* to that value which you want to save.